# Chromedriver Mavericks Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, osx-mavericks

With the Python bindings, I am running into issues starting chromedriver. I (perhaps in a bit of haste) installed the Mavericks upgrade for OS X. When I first tried running the chromedriver, I received an Unknown Error: Chromedriver failed to start. (Chromedriver 2.2, 2.3, and 2.4).

After doing some reading I found a suggested workaround for using verbose mode (Chromedriver 2.4, Chrome version 30.0.1599.101). Now, I'm still not able to start it, but I'm receiving a different error, this time after the browse has opened up:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u"Unknown command 
'WaitForAllTabsToStopLoading'. Options: AcceptOrDismissAppModalDialog, 
ActionOnSSLBlockingPage, ActivateTab, AddBookmark, AddDomEventObserver, AppendTab, 
ApplyAccelerator, BringBrowserToFront, ClearEventQueue, CloseBrowserWindow, CloseTab, 
CreateNewAutomationProvider, DeleteCookie, DeleteCookieInBrowserContext, 
DoesAutomationObjectExist, DragAndDropFilePaths, ExecuteJavascript,
ExecuteJavascriptInRenderView, GetActiveTabIndex, GetAppModalDialogMessage, 
GetBookmarkBarStatus, GetBookmarksAsJSON, GetBrowserInfo, GetBrowserWindowCount, 
GetChromeDriverAutomationVersion, GetCookies, GetCookiesInBrowserContext, 
GetDownloadDirectory, GetExtensionsInfo, GetIndicesFromTab, GetLocalStatePrefsInfo,
GetMultiProfileInfo, GetNextEvent, GetPrefsInfo, GetProcessInfo, GetSecurityState, 
GetTabCount, GetTabIds, GetTabInfo, GetViews, GoBack, GoForward, InstallExtension, 
IsDownloadShelfVisible, IsFindInPageVisible, IsMenuCommandEnabled, IsPageActionVisible, 
IsTabIdValid, MaximizeView, NavigateToURL, OpenFindInPage, OpenNewBrowserWindow, 
OpenNewBrowserWindowWithNewProfile, OpenProfileWindow, OverrideGeoposition, 
RefreshPolicies, Reload, RemoveBookmark, RemoveEventObserver, ReparentBookmark, 
RunCommand, SendWebkitKeyEvent, SetBookmarkTitle, SetBookmarkURL, SetCookie, 
SetCookieInBrowserContext, SetDownloadShelfVisible, SetExtensionStateById, 
SetLocalStatePrefs, SetPrefs, SetViewBounds, SimulateAsanMemoryBug, 
TriggerBrowserActionById, TriggerPageActionById, UninstallExtensionById, 
UpdateExtensionsNow, WaitForBookmarkModelToLoad, WaitUntilNavigationCompletes, 
WebkitMouseButtonDown, WebkitMouseButtonUp, WebkitMouseClick, WebkitMouseDoubleClick, 
WebkitMouseDrag, WebkitMouseMove, AcceptCurrentFullscreenOrMouseLockRequest,
AddOrEditSearchEngine, AddSavedPassword, CloseNotification, 
DenyCurrentFullscreenOrMouseLockRequest, DisablePlugin, EnablePlugin, FindInPage, 
GetAllNotifications, GetDownloadsInfo, GetFPS, GetHistoryInfo, GetInitialLoadTimes,
GetNTPInfo, GetNavigationInfo, GetOmniboxInfo, GetPluginsInfo, GetSavedPasswords,
GetSearchEngineInfo, GetV8HeapStats, IsFullscreenBubbleDisplayed,
IsFullscreenBubbleDisplayingButtons, IsFullscreenForBrowser, IsFullscreenForTab, 
IsFullscreenPermissionRequested, IsMouseLockPermissionRequested, IsMouseLocked, 
KillRendererProcess, LaunchApp, LoadSearchEngineInfo, OmniboxAcceptInput, 
OmniboxMovePopupSelection, PerformActionOnDownload, PerformActionOnInfobar, 
PerformActionOnSearchEngine, RemoveNTPMostVisitedThumbnail, RemoveSavedPassword, 
RestoreAllNTPMostVisitedThumbnails, SaveTabContents, SetAppLaunchType, SetOmniboxText, 
SetWindowDimensions, WaitForAllDownloadsToComplete, WaitForNotificationCount, "
```

Comment: For the original error, I tried version 2.2, 2.3, and 2.4. I ran the verbose version on chromedriver 2.4. Chrome version is 30.0.1599.101

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. Added my env info to the ticket as well. Thanks!

Comment: @qaduderino There have been a few updates to chromedriver since this question was posted. Have you tried chromedriver 2.6? It's solved all Mavericks issues for me.

Comment: Just downloaded it, working for me now! Thanks @TrevorBurnham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appears to have been fixed in chromedriver 2.6: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=599